# Regression curves of y on x and of x on y

Tags: r, regression, linear

For any given value of x, say $X$, the distribution of y is called a y-array. Which is of course the conditional distribution of y given that $x = X$, which looks like:
$$\bar{y}_X = E(y|X)$$
which will be a function of X, and vary with it. However, what does it mean to say - by considering the x-array for $y = Y$, we have
$$\bar{x}_Y = E(x|Y)$$

Would this be similar to the following r-expression?

````
df <- structure(list(Age = c(0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4.5, 4.5, 
4.5, 5, 5, 5, 5.5, 6, 6), Maint = c(182L, 163L, 978L, 466L, 549L, 
495L, 723L, 681L, 619L, 1049L, 1033L, 890L, 1522L, 1194L, 987L, 
764L, 1373L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -17L))

#E(y|X)
lm(Maint ~ Age, data=df)

#E(x|Y)
lm(Age ~ Maint, data=df)
```
````

Comment: `lm` stands for linear model, so you'd impose a linear relationship to estimate the conditional expectation.

Comment: @ChristophHanck Isn't this what the linear regression modelling does, or am I mistaken? Perhaps, the above was referring to a different number of response variables on the predictors. I only ask this question, because I wanted to know how else I could calculate the angle between two linear equations.

Comment: Yes, but a conditional expectation need not be linear.